# ARKit how to draw face mesh?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to draw the [face mesh in real time](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MpoV1YhrPug/maxresdefault.jpg) as is shown in the [Apple video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/601). It's also being done in the [MeasureKit's app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ar-measurekit/id1258270451?mt=8) too. I got the [ARSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession) running which constantly delivers updated ARFrame objects in delegate and I can get [ARFaceAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor) from it which contains the face geomatery consisting of [ARFaceGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacegeometry) and blendShapes. How to use the ARFaceGeometry data to draw the mesh in real time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create a face mesh in augmented reality. I'd recommend using the following innovative approach which utilises ARSCNViewDelegate.

For example:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    guard let device = sceneView.device else {
      return nil
    }
    let faceGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device)
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: faceGeometry)
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .lines
    return node
  }
}
```

In this example, we created a face geometry to be rendered.
Next, we need a SceneKit node based on that face geometry.
We require the fill mode for the node’s material to be fine lines. This should achieve the face mesh that you're after. A further approach to this would be for the face mesh to react to facial expressions.